# Loading user specified IDA symbols in GDB

Tags: ida, gdb

While reversing a binary, whatever symbols we name inside IDA IDB database, is it possible to load the same in GDB while debugging? e.g. I tried [wsym](https://github.com/wapiflapi/wsym) which attempts to inject those as symbols. However, the project seems to be in too beta to work properly. I want to use `pwndbg` for debugging, so using IDA's integrated remote debugging support is not really an option.

Comment: out of interest, what specifically makes IDA's debugger "not an option"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of this year's Recon talks was on a project which exports data from IDA as DWARF debug info. In theory that can be used in `gdb` to provide symbols.

- [Slides](https://recon.cx/2017/montreal/resources/slides/RECON-MTL-2017-Exporting-IDA-Debug-Information.pdf)
- [Code](http://github.com/alschwalm/dwarfexport)

P.S. according to `pwndbg` documentation, it already has some kind of ["IDA integraton"](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg/blob/dev/FEATURES.md#ida-pro-integration), so I'd suggest you to try that and contact the project if you can't get it working.

Comment: `pwndbg` integration works for me, thanks :) However, in the next IDA versions, we'd love to see this feature out of the box, i.e. in principle,IDA can rewrite the ELF binary with symbol integration integrated.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock feel free to send feature requests to support.