# Generating symbol file for closed-source binary by hand

Tags: gdb, debugging-symbols

I have a closed-source binary (`minecraft-pi`). For a given section of the assembly like so:

```
   a2ed4:       e92d45f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sl, lr}
   a2ed8:       e1a04000        mov     r4, r0
   a2edc:       e59d0024        ldr     r0, [sp, #36]   ; 0x24
   a2ee0:       e352007f        cmp     r2, #127        ; 0x7f
   a2ee4:       d3a02000        movle   r2, #0
   a2ee8:       c3a02001        movgt   r2, #1
   a2eec:       e1922fa0        orrs    r2, r2, r0, lsr #31
   a2ef0:       1a000015        bne     a2f4c
```

conveniently there's another binary `libminecraftpe.so` that has code with symbols while containing similar disassembled instructions, and similar relative placement among functions e.g.:

```
0013a3ac <_ZN5Level11hasChunksAtEiiiiii>:
  13a3ac:       e92d 43f8       stmdb   sp!, {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, lr}
  13a3b0:       2a7f            cmp     r2, #127        ; 0x7f
  13a3b2:       4604            mov     r4, r0
  13a3b4:       9809            ldr     r0, [sp, #36]   ; 0x24
  13a3b6:       bfd4            ite     le
  13a3b8:       2200            movle   r2, #0
  13a3ba:       2201            movgt   r2, #1
  13a3bc:       ea52 72d0       orrs.w  r2, r2, r0, lsr #31
  13a3c0:       d119            bne.n   13a3f6 <_ZN5Level11hasChunksAtEiiiiii+0x4a>
```

(`_ZN5Level11hasChunksAtEiiiiii` ~ `Level::hasChunksAt(int, int, int, int, int, int)` according to c++filt).

This matches up because despite one being ARM + Linux and the other ARM/Thumb + Android, they come from roughly the same codebase.

It's thus appealing to build a symbol file for `minecraft-pi` by hand and use it in gdb. Even when primarily stepping through assembly it would be very helpful if I could set breakpoints on function names and see informative backtraces.

So if I have written up a map of addresses to symbol names, how can I generate a corresponding symbol file binary (to be loaded in gdb via the `symbol-file` command, or even embedded into the executable)?

I'm familiar with human-readable debug symbol formats like Breakpad syms, but are there tools for generating a DWARF binary in this manner?

I found other questions on Stack Exchange related to IDA integration, `dwarfexport`, `pwndebug`, and `unstrip` (included in links below). florisschabert/unstrip has ARM support but seems to be geared toward inserting symbols based on Objective-C standard libraries, which isn't applicable here. Using IDA with `dwarfexport` could be an option, but I'd prefer a command-line solution that I could script. I'm basically looking for advice on generally recommended practices before I try out these various tools with limited documentation.

Links:

- [How to handle stripped binaries with GDB? No source, no symbols and GDB only shows addresses?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/how-to-handle-stripped-binaries-with-gdb-no-source-no-symbols-and-gdb-only-sho)
- [Loading user specified IDA symbols in GDB](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15899/loading-user-specified-ida-symbols-in-gdb)
- https://github.com/alschwalm/dwarfexport
- https://github.com/pzread/unstrip
- https://github.com/florischabert/unstrip

Comment: These articles might be helpful in the event that you perform manual analysis to recover symbol and section information: 1) https://em386.blogspot.com/2006/10/resolving-elf-relocation-name-symbols.html 2) https://em386.blogspot.com/2006/10/elf-no-section-header-no-problem.html